# How to create/replace Android.mk file to instantiate Notification.TvExtender()

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-tv

My intention is to instantiate a `Notification.TvExtender()` which  is annotated as `@SystemApi` as you can see in `Android_SDK\sources\android-30\android\app\Notification.java` [image: see here]

According to [this medium article](https://igorsteblii.medium.com/android-tv-application-notifications-on-o-c6820ada2086), I would need to modify the `Android.mk` file. Since I don't have this file in my project and I also don't use NDK, how can I create this file?

I manually created the file in a `jni/` folder, but it won't appear in the project. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

To use @SystemApi, you need to build you apk using full AOSP sources.

To do this, you can follow documentation here : https://source.android.com/setup/start?hl=en

You need also to create Android.mk or Android.bp to build your application using private api. (ex : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TvSettings/+/refs/heads/pie-release/Settings/)

Comment: Sounds like running this as root is not sufficient enough. How about getting a certification from Google?

Comment: If you planed to use your application with full treble device you need to place you app in correct partition (/system instead of /product)

Comment: Yes it is under 'system/priv-app/'